# How to notify Intent that data in changed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am using `LocalActivityManager activityManager = getLocalActivityManager();`, I put all my activities to this by `View view = activityManager.startActivity("123", myIntent)`.
There are many activities in this activityManger which are identical by their ID e.g(123).

1 activity hold favorite Items name `FavoriteActivty`. Another activity hold items. All I want to do is to notify `FavoriteActivty` that data has been changed so activity has to refresh itself...
How to do this? I dont want to create that activity again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally got my answer. I used the following method:

```
onAttachedToWindow();
```

It worked for me. As the window comes to front I check look for the changes.

```
onResume() ;
onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I got what you need.
For my understanding you need to set an adapter to this activity...
then you can just handle a list and give the adapter a "notification"

Example:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Module>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, moduleList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and if you change something (I add here an entry to the list):

```
moduleList.add(m);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: You did not even understand what I ask! I am in another activity and want to notify another activity. The way you are doing is in the same activity.

Comment: Ok... that's why i wrote I'm wasn't sure if I got it...
U tried to put an intent and the other activity just checks if this intent exists... if yes you can do what u need